# Laravel 5.7.13 - How to execute oracle PL/SQL Declare-Begin-End statement

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, plsql

I connect to a Oracle DB with "Oracle SQL Developer" tool, and I can run successfully statements like this (for example):

```
DECLARE
p0_ VARCHAR2(32000) := 'Charlie';
p1_ FLOAT := 35;
p2_ VARCHAR2(32000) := 'Spain';
...
BEGIN
Users.Validate(p0_,p1_,p2_ ....);
END;
```

Also, I can run succesfully simple querys like `Select * from ...`. The server responses in 4-5 seconds.

My problem:
I have a Laravel 5.7.13 project with oracle connection (yajra/laravel-oci8 module) and its works ok when I run simple querys like `Select ...`:

```
DB::select("Select ...");
```

But I can not run the beginning statement:

```
DB::select("DECLARE
    p0_ VARCHAR2(32000) := 'Charlie';
    p1_ FLOAT := 35;
    p2_ VARCHAR2(32000) := 'Spain';
    ...
    BEGIN
    Users.Validate(p0_,p1_,p2_ ....);
    END;");
```

I also tried with `DB::Select(DB::raw("DECLARE ..."))` statement, and `DB::Statement(...)` but not working.

I am using Xampp and apache, and when I try to run this statements, Apache does not responds, no errors, simply it looks like is trying to execute the statement, but not finishes, even though I have a timeout of 10 seconds (`max_execution_time=10` in php.ini, and also forced by my php code with the instruction: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 10)`).

How can I execute this kind of statement from Laravel?
Could be a user permissions problem? (I have configured in Laravel and "Oracle SQL Developer" tool the same user and connection)

Thanks!

Comment: Tried `DB::statement` yet?

Comment: Yes, I have indicated in the description, DB::select, DB::statement don't get response, neither have result on the database. Is there any other way to execute this type of query to the database?

Answer (score 1):

As far as concernes, it is not possible to execute a PL/SQL block directly from Lavarel.

So the best (only ?) option would be to first create a stored procedure directly in the database, using SQLDeveloper or another Oracle client, and then to invoke it from Lavarel, passing it the relevant arguments.

Here is an example based on your use case :

1) Create the stored procedure (NB : the max size of an Oracle `varchar2` is 4000, not 32000) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc
(
    p0 IN VARCHAR2(4000),
    p1 IN FLOAT,
    p2 IN VARCHAR2(4000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    Users.Validate(p0,p1,p2);
END;
```

2) Call the stored procedure from Lavarel :

```
DB::statement('exec myproc("Charlie", 35, "Spain")');
```

If you need to return something from the procedure, use `DB::select` instead of `DB::statement`.